# What are GitLab's repo & users limits

Tags: gitlab

I'm wondering if there's any cap on number of repositories and users allowed in GitLab, given 2GB memory with 2 processing cores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mainly specified in [GitLab requirements](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/requirements.md) document (like [CPU section](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/requirements.md#cpu))

> 2 cores is the recommended number of cores and supports up to 500 users
>
> You need at least 2GB of addressable memory (RAM + swap) to install and use GitLab!
> 2GB RAM is the recommended memory size and supports up to 500 users